# closure js framework - converting ArrayBuffer to string

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-closure

I'm working on a javascript app that uses the [closure framework](https://github.com/google/closure-library/) (https://github.com/google/shaka-player).

I'm receiving an ajax response with a 403 response and I need to parse out the response body to determine detail.

The xhr_.responseType is set as arraybuffer - so I want to be able to convert the response to a string to read its content:

```
if (this.xhr_.responseType == 'arraybuffer')
{
    var ab = new Uint8Array(this.xhr_.response);
    console.log(this.xhr_.response);
    console.log(ab);
}
```

Building with the closure framework, I get the following error:

```
./build/../build/../lib/util/ajax_request.js:441: ERROR - actual parameter 1 of Uint8Array does not match formal parameter
found   : *
required: (Array.<number>|ArrayBuffer|ArrayBufferView|null|number)
      var ab = new Uint8Array(this.xhr_.response);
```

So I'm finding it impossible to pass the response into the Uint8Array constructor.  Is there a way to cast the response to keep closure quiet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If responsetype is arraybuffer, then You will need to loop through in this way:

```
if (this.xhr_.responseType == 'arraybuffer')
{
    var ab = new Uint8Array(this.xhr_.response);
    for (var i = 0, buffer = ''; i < ab.length; i++) 
    {
        buffer += String.fromCharCode(payload[i]);
    }

}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks, but my problem was that var ab = new Uint8Array(this.xhr_.response); was failing.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that works - how to cast in the Closure framework - I hope this helps someone

```
if (this.xhr_.responseType == 'arraybuffer')
{
    var response = /** @type {ArrayBuffer} */ (this.xhr_.response);
    var sBuffer = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(response));
    console.log('response ArrayBuffer to string: ' + sBuffer);
}
```

Comment: Not dependent on the Closure framework. This works nicely for vanilla, should you ever need to convert an ArrayBuffer to a string.

Comment: I guess - but the dependent part is that the /** @type {ArrayBuffer} */ actually has the effect of a cast in the closure framework - the build will fail without this.